# "Persistently" Impure (IO) Vectors in Haskell, with database-like persistent interface

Tags: haskell

I have a computation that is best described as iterative mutations on a vector; the final result is the final state of the vector.

The "idiomatic" approach to making this functional, I think, is to simply pass on a new vector object along whenever it is "modified".  So your iterative method would be `operate_on_vector :: Vector -> Vector`, which takes in a vector and outputs the modified vector, which is then fed through the method again.

This method is pretty straightforward and I had no problems implementing it, even being new to Haskell.

Alternatively, one could encapsulate all of this in a `State` monad and pass along a constantly re-created and modified vector as the state value.

However, I suffer a huge, huge performance cost, as these calculations are pretty intensive, the iterations many (on the order of millions) and the data vectors can get pretty large (on the order of at least thousands of primitives).  Re-creating a new vector in memory at every step of the iteration seems pretty costly, data collection or not.

Then I considered how `IO` works -- it can be seen as basically like `State`, except the state value is the "World", which is constantly changing.

Maybe I could use something that is like `IO` to "operate" on a "world"?  And the "world" would be the vector in-memory?  Sort of like a database query, but everything is in memory.

For example with io you could do

```
do
  putStrLn "enter something"
  something <- getLine
  putStrLine $ "you entered " ++ something
```

which can be seen as "performing" `putStrLn` and "modifying" the World object, returning a new World object and feeding it into the next function, which queryies the world object for a string that is the result of the modification, and then returns another world object after another modification.

Is there anything like that that can do this for mutable vectors?

```
do
  putInVec 0 9          -- index 0, value 9
  val <- getFromVec 0
  putInVec 0 (val + 1)
```

, with "impure" "mutable" vectors, instead of passing along a new modified vector at each step.

Comment: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad/ST ?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're looking for. You could be looking for mutable vectors in the generic sense. You could be looking for ST specifically, with its external purity. You could be looking for something like the now-deprecated `DiffArray`, presenting a persistent interface to mutable arrays. (Though those ended up being too slow to be usable in most cases.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you can do this using [mutable vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.10.0.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Mutable.html) and a thin wrapper over Reader + ST (or IO) monad.

It can look like this:

```
type MyVector = IOVector $x  -- Use your own elements type here instead of $x
newtype VectorIO a = VectorIO (ReaderT MyVector IO a) deriving (Monad, MonadReader, MonadIO)
-- You will need GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving extension here

-- Run your computation over an existing vector
runComputation :: MyVector -> VectorIO a -> IO MyVector
runComputation vector (VectorIO action) = runReaderT action vector >> return vector

-- Run your computation over a new vector of the specified length
runNewComputation :: Int -> VectorIO a -> IO MyVector
runNewComputation n action = do
  vector <- new n
  runComputation vector action

putInVec :: Int -> $x -> VectorIO ()
putInVec idx val = do
  v <- ask
  liftIO $ write v idx val

getFromVec :: Int -> VectorIO $x
getFromVec idx = do
  v <- ask
  liftIO $ read v idx
```

That's really all. You can use `VectorIO` monad to perform your computations, just like you wanted in your example. If you do not want IO but want pure computations, you can use `ST` monad; modifications to the code above will be trivial.

**Update**

Here is an ST-based version:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses, Rank2Types #-}
module Main where

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.Reader.Class
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Vector as V
import Data.Vector.Mutable as MV

-- Your type of the elements
type E = Int

-- Mutable vector which will be used as a context
type MyVector s = MV.STVector s E

-- Immutable vector compatible with MyVector in its type
type MyPureVector = V.Vector E

-- Simple monad stack consisting of a reader with the mutable vector as a context 
-- and of an ST action
newtype VectorST s a = VectorST (ReaderT (MyVector s) (ST s) a) deriving Monad

-- Make the VectorST a reader monad
instance MonadReader (MyVector s) (VectorST s) where
    ask = VectorST $ ask
    local f (VectorST a) = VectorST $ local f a
    reader = VectorST . reader

-- Lift an ST action to a VectorST action
liftST :: ST s a -> VectorST s a
liftST = VectorST . lift

-- Run your computation over an existing vector
runComputation :: MyVector s -> VectorST s a -> ST s (MyVector s)
runComputation vector (VectorST action) = runReaderT action vector >> return vector

-- Run your computation over a new vector of the specified length
runNewComputation :: Int -> VectorST s a -> ST s (MyVector s)
runNewComputation n action = do
  vector <- MV.new n
  runComputation vector action

-- Run a computation on a new mutable vector and then freeze it to an immutable one
runComputationPure :: Int -> (forall s. VectorST s a) -> MyPureVector
runComputationPure n action = runST $ do
  vector <- runNewComputation n action
  V.unsafeFreeze vector

-- Put an element into the current vector
putInVec :: Int -> E -> VectorST s ()
putInVec idx val = do
  v <- ask
  liftST $ MV.write v idx val

-- Retrieve an element from the current vector
getFromVec :: Int -> VectorST s E
getFromVec idx = do
  v <- ask
  liftST $ MV.read v idx
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm lookins for, thanks :)  Just as a follow up, how would I go about turning it into `ST`?  Just replace all `IO` with `ST`s?

Comment: It turned out to be more complex than I thought, mainly because `ST` monad requires special type parameter which breaks autoderiving. See an updated answer.

Comment: thank you for your help :)  all of the monad tutorials i read seem to always leave out ST and some even Reader so this was nice to point me in the right direction